# Track Completed state for messages in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a request to implement a dashboard with the information about which message in Azure Service Bus queue was completed when (with some info about message parameters). Unfortunately we do not have an access to the reciever's code and cannot change the code to log the time of the message delivery. So, we need to subscribe somehow to a moment when reciever takes away the message.

I have already investigated Azure portal API in order to find something, but there is no such a possibility, I have tried to find something on stackoverflow and in Google, but no results.

There is 1 idea: use 2 queues and azure function between them. Put all messages to the first queue, azure function recieves a message, logs the info about the message and puts it to the second queue and waits until other services takes the message away from the second queue. Second queue will always have only 1 message and this way we will be able to understand what message was for sure delivered and when.

However what I do not like is the second message queue executes not the role of the real queue (it means something is wrong here and I need to use something else), performance of such a system can be not high enough...

Any help is appreciated (articles, videos, ideas). Thank you.

Comment: Can you instrument the host where receiver app runs? Then perhaps App Insights could capture the activity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#tracking-with-azure-application-insights

Comment: Once a message is completed, it is removed from the queue. What you can do is store the information in a database like Azure Table Storage or Cosmos DB.

Comment: Would [peek-lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read) receive mode help you? This gives you control over message completion, and you can then log the time when to mark it as complete in your code.

Comment: Recievers are IOT sensors and we have no control of them. It means I cannot change the code of sensors of another company... looks like also cannot use peek-lock